# Sliding a UIView to partially overlay another UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios

It's been a couple of hours since I've been searching on how to do the animation as stated above. So far, I've found this [folding navigation](http://www.honcheng.com/2012/02/Playing-with-folding-navigations) by honcheng and it's quite cool. However, what I want is a bit simpler than this. The way the google map is being brought out from the right side, that's what I wish minus the flipping page effect. Somehow like the way [Pulse](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/411/pulsenewshighlighted.png/) news for iPad does which is also awesome.

So yeah, if anyone has done this, can you suggest some ideas on how can I learn this. Or perhaps an open source which I could look on, and do reverse engineering instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should help you, although keep in mind I'm not very familiar with the animations used in Pulse.

.h declare a `UIView` named secondView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    secondView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480)];
    [secondView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:secondView];
}

- (IBAction)myAction:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.45 animations:^{
        if (secondView.transform.tx == 0) {
            [secondView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-200, 0)];
        }else{
            [secondView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)];
        }

    }];
}
```

Then simply link this action to a button that won't be blocked by your new incoming view!

Comment: I'd try this one out. Thanks! You should find time to try Pulse :) It is awesome specially the iPad version. Plus it is free.

Comment: By the way, what frameworks does this require? Just making sure.

Comment: @Grauzten I've heard about it a couple times before and I've never heard anything bad, I'm going to have to check it out! And it doesn't require any additional frameworks.

Comment: Great! once you've tried it you'll get what I wish to have. Take note of what happens when you tap on any articles shown in grid view.

Comment: @Grauzten any time, happy to help!