# Slide out navigation through swipes for UIView to overlay another UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

On my research regarding this navigation technique, I've found [this post by Nick Harris](http://nickharris.wordpress.com/2012/02/05/ios-slide-out-navigation-code/) which is a good start I suppose. However, what I want is slightly different from this. You can think of it as iOS' `Notification Center` when you just have to swipe from the top to show the `view` and just swipe back to hide it again. In my case, I wish to reveal a hidden `UIView` coming from the right side of the screen with a swipe gesture to the left and also hide it again through the same gesture (this time to the right).

I've managed to get a solution on my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000995/sliding-a-uiview-to-partially-overlay-another-uiview) regarding showing/hiding a UIView. One thing I wish to add is the swiping gesture.

I wouldn't want to tweak my app delegate to do this as Nick Harris has done. So if anyone has any ideas/code samples on how I could do this, I'd be much grateful.

Shed some light :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reveal a hidden UIView coming from the right side of the screen with a swipe gesture to the left and also hide it again through the same gesture (this time to the right). adding transition.

Add BOOL didNotSwipe in .h file add its value didNotSwipe = TRUE in .m file viewDidLoad method

Add swipe gesture with left and right direction with different selector to your self.view.

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight:)];
[recognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[recognizer release]; 

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer1;
recognizer1 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeleft:)];
[recognizer1 setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer1];
[recognizer1 release];
```

When swipe left this method is called:

```
 -(void)swipeleft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeGesture 
 {
   if (didNotSwipe) {
     didNotSwipe = FALSE;
     CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
     [animation setDelegate:self];
     [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
     [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
     [animation setDuration:0.50];
     [animation setTimingFunction:
     [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
     [self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:kCATransition];
     [self.view addSubView:self.overlayView];
     //[self.overlayView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.overlayView.frame.size.width,self.overlayView.frame.size.height)];
   }
 }
```

when swipe right this method:

```
 -(void)swipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeGesture
 {
   if(!didNotSwipe){
     didNotSwipe = TRUE;
     CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
     [animation setDelegate:self];
     [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
     [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
     [animation setDuration:0.40];
     [animation setTimingFunction:
     [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
     [self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:kCATransition];
     [self.overlayView removeFromSuperView];
   }
 }
```

Comment: Halu, I've tried this code already. For the feedback when I swipe to the right, the overlay view comes out good. But when I swipe again to the right, the overlay view disappears for a quick moment and then just appear again. Next, when I do swiping to the left, the overlay view suddenly just disappears so fast. Even if I set the animation's duration to 2.5, still the overlay view disappears fast.

Comment: add a flag which will be true intially in vieDidLoad.Now in swipe to right method if(flag){ flag = FALSE; all other code here} . Now in swipe to left flag = TRUE; this for only one time swiping in any direction

Comment: **EDIT** from my first comment here:
Halu, I've tried this code already. For the feedback when I swipe to the left, the overlay view comes out good. But when I swipe again to the left, the overlay view disappears for a quick moment and then just appear again. Next, when I do swiping to the right, the overlay view suddenly just disappears so fast. Even if I set the animation's duration to 2.5, still the overlay view disappears fast.

Comment: I added the flag already and as regards your suggestion, I just changed the if(flag) condition to swipe to left method and in swipe to right method I set the flag to be TRUE. However, it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: **Feedback from the behavior of the UI with the flag:**
First time swiping to the left is good, UIView goes from right side of the screen and then completely occupy the screen after the animation duration, great! But when I swipe to the right, UIView disappears so fast and it doesn't show the animation happening. Next when I swipe again to the left, a UIView comes from the left side of the screen then disappears and then another UIView comes from the right side of the screen, disappears, and another UIView comes from the right side then completely occupy the screen. Hope you visualized it.

Comment: Thanks for coming up with the suggestion. Upon using the two methods you've provided, the animation feels more like browsing through images. The entire view as well as the secondView moves during swipe gestures. What I wish is for the secondView to be the only view that's moving.

Comment: better use UINavigationController for this.

Comment: Alright, if you have any links on how I could use that I'd be much happy. But thanks though for spending some time for this.