# how to use customize overlay view in different UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am using custom overlay UIView class

```
#import "OverLayView.h"

@implementation OverLayView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
       self->overLay  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 704)];
        self->overLay.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.5];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)removeOverLay{

    [self->overLay removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I am loading on tap action

```
   OverLayView *m_overLay = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:
                              CGRectMake(0,0,1004,768)]; 
    [m_overLay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0. green:0.39 blue:0.106 alpha:0.5]];
    [self.view addSubview:m_overLay];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 704);

    secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [secondViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(300, 60, 430, 620)];
    [self.view addSubview:secondViewController.view];
```

I am getting warring incompatible pointer types initializing overlay view *_strong' with an expression of type UIView.

When i load i need to call the removeOVerLay from secondViewController Which will remove the overlay which has been created

Can any one advice me how to remove the overlay

@thanks in advance

Comment: for warning! pointer types initializing overlay view *_strong  change UIView to OverLayView OverLayView *m_overLay = [[OverLayView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1004,768)];

Answer (score 0):

U can customize overlay view in UIViewController by giving animation effect.

Refer [overlay-another-uiview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066200/slide-out-navigation-through-swipes-for-uiview-to-overlay-another-uiview/12066416#comment16175819_12066416) link. Hope Hopeful

Answer (score 0):

> using NSNotification  solve the issue!